# Callable class interface inheritance typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to define an interface which I can implement with inheritance in another Python class. This interface is meant to pass through the parameter types for the `__call__` implementation. Unfortunately, for the child class with an implementation, the argument typing is not working properly. Effectively, I am trying to treat a class like a Callable with the typing utility included. Alternatively, if anyone knows a way to inherit Callable, that would probably work too.

I am trying to achieve this by defining a class FunctionInterface using Python's Abstract Base Classes (ABC) and Generic Type Variables from the typing module.

In my code, I have:

1. Imported necessary modules: abc, typing, and typing_extensions. I've also imported the ParamSpec and TypeVar typing utilities.
2. Defined the type variables PARAMS (as a ParamSpec) and VALUE (as a TypeVar). I am planning to use these for the input parameters and the return value of the `__call__` method, respectively.
3. Defined the FunctionInterface class as an abstract base class inheriting from ABC and Generic[PARAMS, VALUE]. This allows the class to be treated as a generic type with parameters PARAMS and VALUE.
4. Defined the FunctionBase class, which is a concrete implementation of the FunctionInterface class. It has a `__call__` method that takes an int as input and returns an int.
5. Created instances of the FunctionInterface and FunctionBase classes, named inter and impl, respectively.

However, the current code does not enforce type checking for the `__call__` method

Any help to getting the typing working properly would be appreciated.

```
from abc import ABC  # , abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, TypeVar

from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

PARAMS = ParamSpec("PARAMS")
VALUE = TypeVar("VALUE")


# class FunctionInterface(Generic[PARAMS, VALUE], ABC):
class FunctionInterface(ABC, Generic[PARAMS, VALUE]):
    # @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        ...


class FunctionBase(FunctionInterface):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("FunctionBase.__init__")

    def __call__(self, whatever: int) -> int:
        return whatever


kunc: Callable[[str, int], int] = lambda x, y: int(x) + y
inter: FunctionInterface[[str], str] = FunctionInterface()
impl: FunctionInterface[[str, Any], str] = FunctionBase()
ret = impl(100)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your post accordingly. A few suggestions: Do not describe in _prose_ what you will show in code. The code can speak for itself. In your text you should instead explain briefly and clearly what your goal is, what the desired output of your minimal code example is and what the actual output/error was.

Comment: As it stands, your post is very confusing. What does it mean that it _"does not enforce type checking"_? Why do you need something _other_ than `Callable`? What is your special construct supposed to do that `Callable` _cannot_ do?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=a2c098d23211934d77584ca2ef3ab248)? Or are `__init__` args somehow related to `__call__` parameters? This is really unclear. What's the point of ABC without abstract methods?

Comment: @SUTerliako Thank you for answering, it is along the lines of what I wanted but the static type checker just didn't comply. It shows "(variable) impl: FunctionBase" instead of the desired "(variable) impl: FunctionInterface[(int), int]" or thereabouts. Do you know how to fix that?